# Wrong sort order in category product collection

Tags: product-collection, enterprise-1.13, position, category-products

I am trying to get the product collection based on the position (defined in Category Products in admin) in the category, but it doesn't work with product collection object whereas works correctly with product collection array (getData())

```
E.g. in Admin > Manage Categories > Category > Category Products 
(Is Anchor = true but no sub-categories)
Product | Position
Prod A  | 1
Prod B  | 2
```

When I loop through product collection `$_productCollection` in catalog/product/list.phtml file, the product's order comes Prod B and then Prod A, whereas if I use `$_productCollection->getData()` and loop through it, it gives products in correct order.

`foreach($_productCollection as $_product) //gives Prod B and then Prod A, which is not expected`

`foreach($_productCollection->getData() as $_product) //gives Prod A and then Prod B, which is correct`

Any ideas why it would behave differently when accessing it as an object and as an array, on the same collection?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you do to add the sorting?

Comment: Nothing, that's the default Magento code only.

Comment: That's probably because you're not accessing the same stuff, if you debug $_productCollection you'll see tons of stuff and a huge array called "data".

Comment: @JulienLachal Could be, but I am just looping it over as we do for any other collection. `foreach($_productCollection as $_product)`. Actually it did got auto-fixed but not sure whether this problem will start again or not.

Comment: maybe has to do with data reindexing?

Comment: I tried that as well many times.. By re-indexing catalog products and also re-indexing all the indexes. That didn't changed anything. Weird I know!

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the files which are relevant for this, I can identify `Varien_Data_Collection` which is the base class and implements `IteratorAggregate`, so you can loop over collections using `foreach($_productCollection as $product)`.

It does so via the method getIterator() which mainly returns new `ArrayIterator($this->_items);`

In contrast, a level further up extending from `Varien_Data_Collection` there is the class `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`.

This class implements the method getData() as follows:

```
public function getData()
{
    if ($this->_data === null) {
        $this->_renderFilters()
             ->_renderOrders()
             ->_renderLimit();
        $this->_data = $this->_fetchAll($this->_select);
        $this->_afterLoadData();
    }
    return $this->_data;
}
```

It explicitly uses the `_renderOrders()` method which adds an order clause to the select statement.
This is why `getData()` will use your given order, but the default iteration will not.

Comment: Nice to know, so is there any way I can get collection object to use my sort order? I tried adding "ORDER BY" clause without any luck on collection. It does show in query but not when I loop through the object.